# lowercase 'x' key not working as root under linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

This is a weird one. The title says it all - The lowercase letter 'x' has stopped working as root. It works just fine for other users, and the uppercase form works (Though of course with case sensitivity, not for all cases of use).

Under the console, as well as in a terminal (Also within a user-initiated tmux session under su-to-root), pressing 'x' simply doesn't work. Though I have a feeling that what I was doing when this problem arose is irrelevant, I came across this in the middle of trying to get this laptop working with the nvidia drivers (Also no luck so far but that's something I have no time to solve or ability to fix until I get this working), where at one moment it worked (For commands, again, to get the nvidia server working -- for example, 'startx', or exiting the root login with 'exit').

I'll probably need to provide more information in this in future edits to this post, but my operating system here is as follows from uname -a:

```
Linux [hostname ommitted] 3.12-0.slh.3-aptosid-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 19 01:45:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Sounds like a weird key binding. Try if the `x` key is working after invoking a clean shell: `bash --norc` (you don't need a `x` for that `;)`).

Comment: Seems that isn't the ticket. Still not working.

Comment: Did you try it as `su root bash --norc` or `sudo bash --norc` (starting from a normal shell in which the ‘x’ key works)? If you become root and then exit from the shell with (Ctrl)+(D) or `kill –KILL $$`, does the ‘x’ key work then?

Comment: Doesn't seem either of these get the x key working.